# Where does make store its cache?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

*Make* seems to compare a file modification time with some sort of internal cache of modification times. Does anyone know where is this cache located or how to access it?

Comment: I think it only checks if any of the sources is newer than the result

Comment: Sami is correct. There is no cache.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use a utility such as `strace` to see what it's doing.  Here we can follow all file actions (`-e trace=file`) that the make program performs.

Let's say that we have `foo.c` and a `foo` which is built from it using a simple Makefile that looks like:

```
$ cat Makefile
foo: foo.c
```

Let's run `make`:

```
$ strace -e trace=file make
execve("/usr/bin/make", ["make"], [/* 20 vars */]) = 0
...
open("Makefile", O_RDONLY)              = 3
stat("Makefile", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=11, ...}) = 0
...
stat("foo", 0x7ffd4373c8c0)             = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("foo.c", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=36, ...}) = 0
cc     foo.c   -o foo
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=27717, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
stat("foo", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=8549, ...}) = 0
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Here you see that it checks for the existence of `foo` and fails to find it, it checks for the existence of `foo.c`, and it then calls the rule to compile it.

Now you can call make again, and you get slightly different results:

```
$ strace -e trace=file make
...
stat("foo", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=8549, ...}) = 0
stat("foo.c", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=36, ...}) = 0
make: `foo' is up to date.
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

If there was some kind of a cache file being used, we'd expect to see an `open()` and a `read()` against it.  If this cache was being used between runs, then we'd expect to see a `write()` to it as well.

Answer (score 25):

The *cache* as such is your *file system*:

- The `make` program *reads* the makefile,
- *determines* the list of *targets* and *dependencies*,
- *observes* the timestamps for these targets and dependencies,
- works backward from the target you specify (or the default target, i.e., the first one in the makefile), to find a target whose dependencies are newer.
- it runs the rule for the out-of-date target, and repeats until everything is up to date.

As it performs rules, the target it builds is expected to be updated (newer), but it moves on to the next out-of-date target from its initial inspection of the filesystem even if the target is not actually updated.

Re-executing `make` forces it to start over with the analysis, using the *current* state of your file system.